# Unable to send emails

Tags: email, thunderbird

being new to all this I am asking for help.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and email via thunderbird mail (unknown version, how do I find this) I am receiving emails quite normally but when I try to send them, I am asked for a password.  This has happened suddenly, I have an email password but it tells me it is incorrect.  I have tried Googling help, but the first step is : Go to tools > open account information.??  This is where I crash, under tools there is no account data on the drop down box.  BOTHER....
Please help in simple steps please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/863672/edit) and add more information. Which email service provider are you using? Please take a screenshot of the Thunderbird account information page and add it to the question.

Comment: I am using optusnet.com.au  the errors I do not know how to attach, maybe someone might give me the step by step instructions on how to add a screen shot.

Comment: The screenshots are not related to emails. These seem to be about the printer.

Comment: what email service provider are you trying to etup on Thunderbird ?

Comment: Yes, quite correct.  I do not know how that got on the system, but it is certainly the printer.  I will try again..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       file:///home/rod/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-12-23%2012-47-50.png

Comment: Well that didn't work.  I clicked on copy picture and paste in this forum, it looks like it only gave the address of the pic. and not the actual picture.  I will have to type it in the long way.

Comment: Use in your shell: `thunderbird --version`

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird is prompting for a password because the saved password you have (if you have saved a password) doesn't match the password that is associated with your email account.

The password for reading and sending email is almost always the same.  If you recall the password you used for reading the mail, use that same password when Thunderbird prompts you for the sending email password.

If you don't recall the password, or it doesn't accept the password you typed in, you'll have to **contact your Email provider** and get the correct password.

Your email provider may not be able to tell you your current password.  But they will be able to change it to a new one of your choice.  Use the new password they give you for both reading and sending your emails.

*By the way, if you are having a problems using **Google** that is a separate and unrelated issue.  You can create a separate question to fix your **Google** problem.*